# Codeigniter Update method Issue when adding array values into DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

Trying to update college profile which contains all the college info in the database, Some records are manually filled in by data entry, some records have to be updated by the college admin or super admin.

The issue is when I **insert** an array ***(Facilities[ ])*** into the Db it inserts without any errors, but when i **update** the same it gives me an error.

The Insertion was done through another controller with insert statement

```
$company_id = $this->companies_model->add_company($company_array);
```

which works flawlessly, But update function gives me this error

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

UPDATE `pp_companies` SET  `facilities` = Array,  `company_description` = 'Established in the year....', `company_join` = 'Why Join us',  WHERE `ID` = '201'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\jobportal\jp_sys\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 287

**Facilities = 'Array'? any idea how this shows?**

Array ( [0] => Engineering [1] => Management )
sends the value when i check through

print_r($this->input->post('facilities'));

But it doesnt get updated in the table

**View**

```
<div class="input-group <?php echo (form_error('company_description'))?'has-error':'';?>">
<label class="input-group-addon">College<br> Description <span>*</span></label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="company_description" id="company_description" rows="8" cols="30" ><?php echo $company_description; ?></textarea>
<?php echo form_error('company_description'); ?> </div>

<div class="input-group <?php echo (form_error('company_join'))?'has-error':'';?>">
<label class="input-group-addon">Why join <br> our College? <span>*</span></label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="company_join" id="company_join" rows="8"  cols="30" ><?php echo $company_join; ?></textarea>
<?php echo form_error('company_join'); ?> </div>


<?php echo $facilities ?>                   
<div class="input-group boxwraper <?php echo (form_error('facilities'))?'has-error':'';?>">
<label class="input-group-addon">Facilities Offered <span></span></label>
<select name="facilities[]" class="js-example-tags"  multiple="multiple">
<option value="Library" >Library</option>
<option value="Gym" >Gym</option>
<option value="Canteen" >Canteen</option>
.
.   
</select>                       
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
tags: true
})
</script>
```

**Model**

```
public function add_company($data){

        $return = $this->db->insert('pp_companies', $data);
        if ((bool) $return === TRUE) {
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        } else {
            return $return;
        }       

}   

public function update_company($id, $data){
    $this->db->where('ID', $id);
    $return=$this->db->update('pp_companies', $data);
    return $return;
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Edit_College extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{

    $row = $this->employers_model->get_employer_by_id($this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $data['row'] = $row;
    $data['title'] = $row->company_name.' - Edit Profile';      
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('facilities[]', 'Facilities', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_description', 'Company Description', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags|secure');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_join', 'Company Join', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags|secure');
    $data['facilities'] = (set_value('facilities'))?set_value('facilities'):$row->facilities;
    $data['company_description'] = (set_value('company_description'))?set_value('company_description'):$row->company_description;
    $data['company_join'] = (set_value('company_join'))?set_value('company_join'):$row->company_join;

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('employer/edit_company_profile_view',$data);
        return;
    }

    //for facility addition into db
    $arrcategory1 = $this->input->post('facilities');
    foreach($arrcategory1 as $val1)
    {
        $categoryarr1 = $categoryarr1 . $val1. ",";
   }
   $categoryarr1 = substr(trim($categoryarr1), 0, -1); //rtrim($categoryarr,",")        

    $company_array = array(

                            'facilities'=> $arrcategory1,
                            'company_description' => $this->input->post('company_description'),
                            'company_join' => $this->input->post('company_join'),

    $this->companies_model->update_company($row->company_ID, $company_array);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a><strong>Success!</strong> Your company profile has been updated.</div>');
    $this->session->set_userdata('slug',$company_slug);
    redirect(base_url('employer/edit_college'));
}
```

}

Comment: replace 'facilities'=> $arrcategory1, by 'facilities'=> $categoryarr1, in $company_array in controller.

Comment: you are sending array instead of string

Comment: Thank You so much @hrishi, It works!